# Visual Studio Installer Problem with assembly

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

I am hesitant to ask this question because I feel like it has been answered I just can seem to find it. I have a program that runs fine in Release, however I use the VS Installer and actually install it tells me it can't find the file. I try a bunch of different things to make it work and still nothing. At times I think I made things much worse.

I can build the project find. It has no problems running in VS 2010. I also have no error's  when I build the installer. The file which is the assembly a exe, that is basically acting like DLL. I install the program file, and the program loads fine. When I can a specific function I run into the the missing could not locate file or assembly message.

Comment: Your question is not clear. What File is not fount? During compile time or when you try and run the application? Please clarify.

Comment: Have you verified that all of the dependency's are in the MSI file?

Comment: @PedroC88 I added an update to original post to make it more clear

Comment: I use Orca, some more information is here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370557(v=VS.85).aspx and is part of this download http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=3138

Comment: Is the DLL in your project's "References"? Are you using Visual Studio's installer project?

Comment: @PedroC88 Yes, and Yes I was pretty clear from the first post that I was using VS Installer

Comment: Then it's odd since References should be automatically added to the installer project. I'd for starters go to the installer project and see myself if the missing DLL is contained within.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the reference and downloaded another copy of the library. I added the reference again and made a new install project.

Comment: If that fixed it you can mark your own answer as THE answer for future reference for others.